# Visual studio builds but msbuild does not.

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I have looked at many of the similar questions, none have answered my problem thus far.

I can't build any of the libraries/applications in the project with msbuild.
There are 0 errors, 0 warnings, 0 messages in visual studio.

Even when I isolate the library, none of them compile. 
There are 68 errors for the core library that is not dependant on anything except two nuget packages. Some of the errors include:

**CS1003 Syntax error, ","** expected and
**CS1525 Invalid expression term 'double'**. 
Both On a line like this:
`Function(param1, param2, out double bla, out double blu);`

**CS1003 Syntax error, '[' expected** on a line like this: 
`void FuncPointer() { Obj.Function(); }`

And many other obviously wrong errors but not on every line. Mostly "," expected errors.

Comment: Did you make sure that you are using an MSBuild version that supports C#7?

Comment: Try the one from: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`

Comment: Any update for this issue? You should share a simple sample and the result you build with MSBuild, and the command line you build with MSBuild. Only two compilation errors are hard to see is the problem with MSBuild.

Comment: What version of .NET is your project targetting? What version of MSBUILD are you using?

Comment: @Nekeniehl, I was using that one.

Comment: @DomBurf targeting 4.5.2

Comment: @Leo Liu-MSFT when I was trying to gather this information together I saw that something had caused Illegal characters in a Nuget.config file in AppData. But the project was still getting compiled into a nuget package in visual studio, which is why I didn't notice this. I fixed the appData config up and introduced a local nuget.config in the repo to prevent that error, and the rest of the build was fine in msbuild.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, that something had caused Illegal characters in a Nuget.config file in AppData. But the project was still getting compiled into a nuget package in visual studio, which is why this went unnoticed. All the packages were already installed. I introduced a local nuget.config in the repo to prevent that error, and the rest of the build was fine in msbuild.exe.